# Unable to connect Offset Explorer to Kafka running in docker

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

I have a `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '2'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
    ports:
      - 2181:2181

  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - 9092:9092
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://broker:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
```

The containers (based on these 2 images from this file) works well, but I can't connect to `localhost:9092` (using offset explorer for kafka)
Could you help me understand what is wrong in this `docker-compose.yml` file?

Comment: You want to connect from the host I understand?

Comment: What specific error are you getting from Offset Explorer? Could you download Kafka CLI tools on the host, and use `kafka-topics --list --bootstrap-server localhost:9092`?

Answer (score 3):

Setting up the Bootstrap servers like this under Advanced tabs did the trick for me: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1oru3.png).
In the properties tab, set the Zookeeper Host and port to "localhost" and "2181" .

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a line like this

```
KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://0.0.0.0:9092
```

https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-listeners-explained/

Answer (score 0):

I have added another kafka ui

try this:

```
version: '2'
services:
  kafka-ui:
    container_name: kafka-ui
    image: provectuslabs/kafka-ui:latest
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
      - kafka
    environment:
      KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_NAME: local
      KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_BOOTSTRAPSERVERS: kafka:29092
      KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_METRICS_PORT: 9997
      DYNAMIC_CONFIG_ENABLED: 'true'

  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
    ports:
      - 22181:2181
  
  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - 9092:9092
      - 9997:9997
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_JMX_PORT: 9997
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
```